# Подсвечивание слов в RichEditBox

Tags: c#, uwp

Нужно подсвечивать заданным цветом подстроку в документе RichEditBox. Для этого написал метод:

```
    private async Task ChangeTextColor(string text, Color color)
    {
        string textStr;
        bool theEnd = false;
        int startTextPos = 0;
        myRichEdit.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out textStr);

        while (theEnd == false)
        {
            myRichEdit.Document.GetRange(startTextPos, textStr.Length).GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out textStr);
            var isFinded = myRichEdit.Document.GetRange(startTextPos, textStr.Length).FindText(text, textStr.Length, FindOptions.None);

            if (isFinded != 0)
            {
                string textStr2;
                textStr2 = myRichEdit.Document.Selection.Text;

                var dialog = new MessageDialog(textStr2);
                await dialog.ShowAsync();

                myRichEdit.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.BackgroundColor = color;
                startTextPos = myRichEdit.Document.Selection.EndPosition;
                myRichEdit.Document.ApplyDisplayUpdates();
            }
            else
            {
                theEnd = true;
            }
        } 
    }
```

В отладчике видно, что подстрока находится и isFinded равен количеству символов в найденной подстроке. То есть фрагмент найден и, судя по описанию метода FindText, должен быть выделен, но нет. В textStr2 возвращается пустая строка и соответственно цвет не меняется. Не могу разобраться в чем ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответили на английском StackOverflow:

Ваш код не устанавливает выделение, поэтому myRichEdit.Document.Selection возвращает null. Нужно использовать ITextRange.SetRange для установки выделения и ITextRange.FindText для поиска строки в выделении.

Например:

```
private void ChangeTextColor(string text, Color color)
{
    string textStr;

    myRichEdit.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out textStr);

    var myRichEditLength = textStr.Length;

    myRichEdit.Document.Selection.SetRange(0, myRichEditLength);
    int i = 1;
    while (i > 0)
    {
        i = myRichEdit.Document.Selection.FindText(text, myRichEditLength, FindOptions.Case);

        ITextSelection selectedText = myRichEdit.Document.Selection;
        if (selectedText != null)
        {
            selectedText.CharacterFormat.BackgroundColor = color;
        }
    }
}
```